# Raspberry Pi Local Network serving website with node and controlling analog ouput

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, iot, gpio

I imagine the following setup:

1. A Raspberry Pi creates a local wifi network with a fixed ssid and pw
2. When connected to the network with any device and going to a set ip address, it opens a website served from the Raspberrys Node server. (Static would also be ok)
3. The served Website should be able to control Pin outs of the Raspberry, to control other circuits (GPIO).

What would be the right tech stack to do that and what hardware do I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setup would work to drive the outputs of the Pi. You would need the Raspberry Pi, a Micro SD card (Assuming it is a modern Pi), A USB power plug and some way to connect the outputs. A few jumpers and a breadboard would do the trick but there are also breakout modules available, [image: Breakout Module]

You can then write your own software for the Pi or use something pre-made like, http://webiopi.trouch.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot! This looks really good.
I ended up creating a local wifi and serving a node server that is talking to a python script to control the pins. I'll check that out next time.